# JQuery Ajax not updating record

Tags: php, jquery

I have some jquery ajax code to update a record but it's not working as expected.

Here is the code:

```
    function update_records() {
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST", // Set the type then $_GET['id'] or $_POST['id']
  url: "update_record.php",
  data: { category: "John", image: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});

}; //end function


Then the php

<?php 

  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];


  include 'config.php';


  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET title = 'something' where id=$id"); 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '$id'");             
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);  

?>
```

Comment: Where does the code break? Is the success function called at all? What happens if you open update_record.php in the browser? Where is your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from jQuery.com
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", // Set the type then $_GET['id'] or $_POST['id']
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

I can't understand what your query returns.
Maybe you need to select where `id = $id;`

```
 //  $id = $_POST['id'] or $_GET['id']  Where is $id??? 
  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET title = 'something' where id=$id"); 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '$id'");             
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);    


 //You can use mysql_error() function to see the error.
 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET title = 'something' where id=$id") or    die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I've updated the code to your code but nothing updated and no saved message either

Comment: Now you don't have your 'id' field in 'data', therefore no $_REQUEST['id']

Answer (score 1):

I see you have:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET title = 'something' where id=$id");
```

I don't see where you take the value of `$id`

Answer (score 0):

u need

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

I think you forgot to include this line before executing the update query.